# How to get actionbar back button width programmatically?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am setting toolbar to my actionbar, but I have activities when I disable home button and the title in toolbar is not centralized so I would like to get actionbar back button with programmatically to set `toolbar.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0, 0);`

[image]

Comment: question is unclear

Comment: Can you elaborate what you want to do?

Comment: @Nilu  I uploaded the photo

Comment: You can change the style of back button.

Comment: First, you will have to set activity  theme as No action bar theme and use toolbar bar manually and  set style to make action bar back button visible or stylable .

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like this for the `TextView` inside the Toolbar which contains your title:

```
android:paddingLeft="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
     toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_editprofile);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
  toolbar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.back_arrow));
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set by setting Style, set activity theme in the manifest as no action bar and use toolbar manually in layout and set the style as you want and you can also change the size of text or you can inflate image in toolbar by using style.

```
 <style name="Theme.MyFancyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_toolbar_back_button</item>
</style>

 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
                    android:layout_gravity="top"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    app:theme="@style/Theme.MyFancyTheme">
```